# adding URL to html.grid column

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, spark-view-engine

```
!{Html.Grid(Model.Results)
        .Columns(column =>
        {
          column.For(x => x.Title).Named("Article Name");
          column.For(x => x.Sites);
          column.For(x => x.PreviousPath).Named("Previous Path");
          column.For(x => x.CurrentPath).Named("Current Path");
          column.For(x => x.PreviousUrl).Named("Previous Url");
          column.For(x => x.CurrentUrl).Named("Current Url");
          column.For(x => x.LogDate).Named("Date");
        }
)
  .Empty("There are no R301s.")
}
```

In the above grid I have a CurrentUrl. This URL is pointing to a website. I need to make the Current URL a hyperlink to the same Url.

On the page I have added

```
use namespace="MvcContrib.UI.Grid.ActionSyntax"
```

There is an Action syntax to add hyperlink. I think the code will look something like

column.For(x => x.CurrentUrl).Named("Current Url").Action(href)

Need help with the syntax to add hyperlink to the above column.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you want to use ActionSyntax, you can create the Html.ActionLink independently assuming you know what values are coming in for your href.

If href is an actual URL (http://www.example.com), standard HTML works with Spark:

```
column.For(c => 
           string.Format("<a href='{0}'>{1}</a>", x.Grade, "Previous Url"))
                 .Named("Column Header")
                 .DoNotEncode();
```

If you're building your URL based on a set Action name and Id (such as directing to an edit page):

```
column.For(c => 
           Html.ActionLink("Previous Url", 
                           "Action_Method_Name", 
                           new { controller = "DifferentController", //optional
                                 id = c.YourIdColumnIfRequired  //optional
                               }) 
               .Named("Column Header")
               .DoNotEncode();
```

Comment: .DoNotEncode() in .net 4.5 (earlier maybe?) is now `.Encode(false)`