# How do I add a link action inside a grid/column in MVC using Razor only

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using `Razor` grid system to show a listing. I want to make a column as a link action. But my problem is it's showing the link in the font end as raw HTML file. 
My code is

```
columns.Add(c => c.Title).Titled("Title").Filterable(true).RenderValueAs(c => Html.ActionLink(c.Title, "Details", new { id = c.Id }));
```

There fore the output is 
[image: Output]

I have also used `Format()` in placement of `RenderValueAs()` However the result is same. 
I have studied through from this links.[Link1](https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/3768/how-to-place-hyperlink-in-grid-column), [Link1](https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/Hyperlink-columns-in-ASPNET-MVC-Grid.aspx), [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903726/adding-url-to-html-grid-column), [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059864/asp-net-mvc-making-cell-contents-as-link-in-grid-mvc) But no probable solution is found. 
And I don't want to solve this without any help of javascript or any scripting language. I am looking for only razor related solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly I got a solution of my own question, I have checked it.

Instead of using
 `columns.Add(c => c.Title).Titled("Title").Filterable(true).RenderValueAs(c=>Html.ActionLink(c.Title, "Details", new { id = c.Id }));`

I have used

```
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model);
}
@grid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
        headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
        footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
        alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
        selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
        rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
        mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
        columns:
            grid.Columns(
            grid.Column(columnName: "Student Name", header: "Name", format: @<text>@item.Name</text>),
            grid.Column(columnName: "SchoolName", header: "School Name", format: @<text>@item.SchoolName</text> ),
            grid.Column(columnName: "Address", header: "Address", format: @<text>@item.Address</text>),
            grid.Column(columnName: "City", header: "City", format: @<a>@item.City</a>),
            grid.Column(columnName: "State", header: "State", format: @<text>@item.State</text>)
           ))
```

Here i have attached `<a>` on cities. So therefore I am quiet capable of customize the whole grid by myself as same. From reference [link](https://stick2basic.wordpress.com/2013/04/10/how-to-set-webgrid-style-in-mvc/) i obtained this strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Never used this `grid` thing, just write html tag and loop myself, i think it's more in control.

In this case, i think it's `RenderValueAs` method problem, it maybe decode output.
You can try this `RenderValueAs(c => {string tag = generate your link tag string; return Html.Raw(tag);})`

if it is not working you can write a extension method on `Filterable()`, generate `MvcHtmlString` yourself, it should work.

Comment: Yeah.Previously I have generated this table through looping in my recent and ongoing projects. But this is a obsolete project need to modify. So, the requirements are varies. I am not quiet happy with this types of solution. However, I have to.